# In virtual assitent ,IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter.Adapter.Processasync menthod render the error :"Error invoking the skill id: error code 401."

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We are trying to create virtual assistant bot microsoft teams. When we are trying to send request to skill bot from root bot using SkillClient.PostActivityAsync method, while debugging request hits botcontroller of skill bot. But it return 401 unauthorized error. If we try same in local using bot framework emulator (without using app id and password) it is working as expected. And how we can resolve this unauthorized error?

"When we use root bot with the different simple skill bot, it is working. but when we use app having client app (for tabs and Messaging extensions built using react) and additional authorization required for it. at that time it is throwing the above error"

Thanks!

Comment: Share if there any proper flow of documentation followed to work on this. It will be supportive to repro the issue.

Comment: Can you share the clear flow followed in creating the bot, whether it is single tenant or multi- tenant. Kindly update the region details in which the root bot and client app are operating.